# Invert scroll direction of ScrollViewer in an ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, scroll

For whatever reason, I have an `ItemsControl` which is flipped in Y coordinate, and in it I have a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ItemsControl ...>

    ...

    <ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
    </ItemsControl.LayoutTransform>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    ...

</ItemsControl>
```

Each DataTemplate has a similar transform so text looks correctly.

One issue this creates is scrolling is inverted. Is there anyway to invert the scroll direction? Or do the calculation myself, somehow, instead of the default scroll behavior. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What if you move the ItemsControl's LayoutTransform to the ItemsPresenter? Then the scrollviewer is outside the flipping.

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    ...
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <ItemsPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                    </ItemsPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                </ItemsPresenter>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

OK... so that doesn't work for you.

How about making your own scrollviewer and overriding OnPreviewMouseWheel to invert the mouse wheel's delta change?

```
public class ScrollViewerInvert : System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta != 0)
            e = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta * -1);
        base.OnPreviewMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work correctly. First, the scroll bar is now incorrectly appearing at the top (but the content is at the bottom). Second, scrolling is still inverted.

Comment: @LeoNatan See edit. Maybe I'm not understanding your problem?

Comment: Upvote for creating new EventArgs object, because of a readonly Delta property.